# Average array of values in AVX

Tags: avx, avx2

I have an array of values, in which I have to average 12 consecutive values(input length is always multiples of 12) and replicate it six times in output array.

```
For Example

input = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, 12, soon];

Val1 = mean([a1 to a12]);

Val2 = mean([a13 to a24]);

out = [Val1, Val1, Val1, Val1, Val1, Val1, Val2, soon];
```

Any hints to code this functionalities in AVX?.

Edit:
Values are single precision numbers.

Comment: `uint8` values or `double` values? Have you tried what happens if you do this with a simple C or C++ program compiled with `-O3 -ffast-math -march=haswell`?

Comment: 12 is 3x4, so you can start with two _mm_add_ps, then hsum.  [Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6996764).  (But unlike that Q&A, use shuffles that leave the result in all 4 elements, so you can do a store and a `movlps` 8-byte store.)